# React-native How can I force TabNavigator's child to re-render in TabNavigator?

Tags: react-native

My code is [Here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2407)

I'm using react-navigation `TabNavigator`, `StackNavigator`
I want a component to be `re-rendered` EVERY TIME I navigate to it.
But it was rendered only ONCE when I `navigate` to it.

How can I force `TabNavigator`'s child to `re-render` in TabNavigator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set new parameters when navigating to the screen. This causes react-navigation to invoke a render.

Here's an example from the react-navigation docs:

```
 <Button
      onPress={() => navigate('Profile', {name: 'Brent'})}
      title="Go to Brent's profile"
    />
```

the second parameter to `navigate` is a params object. If you put something random there, it will cause a render every time you call it.